# NullPointerException on Fragment setMenuVisibility(boolean)

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, fragment

I have `BottomNavigationView`with 5 items. Using `Viewpager` and `Adapter` pattern to load the fragments into the container. The crash occurs when the app goes to background then killed by the system and I try to open the app from recents screen will throw this error.

Even though the app looks like it's normally reloading, it crashed (but there is no app crashed dialog) and then reloads the app from start. From the log I understand the fragment is `NULL` but unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong!

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.setMenuVisibility(boolean)' on a null object reference
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:123)
   at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
   at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1224)
   at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
   at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
   at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
   at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
   at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
   at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:742)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24545)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3006)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1833)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2122)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Activity code block,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bottomBar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar_home);
    bottomBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

void initiateAdapter() {
    mHomePagerAdapter = new HomePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(null);
    pager.setAdapter(mHomePagerAdapter);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NAVIGATION_COUNT); // Count is 5
    pager.setCurrentItem(NAVIGATION_HOME);
    bottomBar.setSelectedItemId(getCurrentTabId());
}

private int getCurrentTabId() {
    switch (currentTab) {
        case NAVIGATION_HOME:
            return R.id.navigation_home;

        case NAVIGATION_FRAG_ONE:
            return R.id.navigation_frag_one;

        case NAVIGATION_FRAG_TWO:
            return R.id.navigation_frag_two;

        case NAVIGATION_FRAG_THREE:
            return R.id.navigation_frag_three;

        case NAVIGATION_FRAG_FOUR:
            return R.id.navigation_frag_four;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Adapter code,

```
public class HomePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public HomePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return getFragment(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NAVIGATION_COUNT;
}

private Fragment getFragment(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case NAVIGATION_HOME:
            fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
            break;

        case NAVIGATION_FRAG_ONE:
            fragment = FragmentOne.newInstance();
            break;

        case NAVIGATION_FRAG_TWO:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            break;

        case NAVIGATION_FRAG_THREE:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            break;

        case NAVIGATION_FRAG_FOUR:
            fragment = FragmentFour.newInstance();
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
} }
```

Comment: Your `NAVIGATION_HOME`, `NAVIGATION_FRAG_ONE`... positions start from 0, and not 1, right?

Comment: Yes, starts from 0, ends at 4

Comment: `pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NAVIGATION_COUNT);` instead of count set it to 2

Comment: @ShadowDroid, Can you tell me how setting `setOffscreenPageLimit ` to 2 resolve the problem? And as a feature, I can't do that.

Comment: If you look [official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager#setoffscreenpagelimit) states that - _Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state_ I think you should notice clearly says **pages on sides of current page that means we have to remove current page from count. So it can be `count-1`**. But I would always advice to go for 2

Comment: Since you have mentioned count, and in your case it is 5, so ViewPager will try to load 6 pages in total...which is wrong i guess? Isn't it?

Comment: Actually, your understanding is not right, it the limit to hold number of pages. Which means how much you want to retain in memory. In my case I want to retain totally 5 screens. So my limit is set to 5. If I set to 2, when I switch to fragment 3, the fragment 1 will be destroyed and fragment 2 & 3 will be in memory, when I go to 4, 2 will be destroyed, 3 & 4 will be in memory. This is how it works.

Comment: Ok don't keep 2, go for count-1 instead count and check whether it is still throwing same error.  And my understanding is based on statement in official document which i am quoting again - _number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state_

Comment: Coming to your example - _If I set to 2, when I switch to fragment 3, the fragment 1 will be destroyed and fragment 2 & 3 will be in memory, when I go to 4, 2 will be destroyed, 3 & 4 will be in memory. This is how it works._ Sorry as far my understanding is if current view is in hierarchy then its either side would be retained so if fragment 3 is visible then frag 2 and 4's view will be retained so and so forth